# I have a blazor server side web app created with VS2019. After opening the project with V2022, the web page gives Error on the browser side

Tags: c#, frameworks, blazor-server-side, publish

I have a blazor server side web app created with VS2019. This was working fine until now. Recently I have tried to open the project file from a remote PC with VS2022. During opening the project I didn't get any errors, or any converting informations.
Just I changed the target framework from net 6.0 to .Net Core 3.1, as my project was generated with .Net Core 3.1

After publishing without any errors now I get the following Error on the Browser, when I open the web page:

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The same error is coming even then, when I rebuild and publish the project with my original VS2019.

Also the same error is coming when I rebuild and publish the previous version of the project (that was not opened with VS2022) with VS2019.

I am really shocked. What can I do now? I think that on my publish path (wwwroot) there is something wrong now.

(Normally from now on I want to work with VS2022)